# How to change background of heading which is in loop of twig using Javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, onclick, twig, background-color

I am new to JavaScript. I want to display names that are in an array and each name with data are put in heading tag . I want to change the background color of the heading with each click on the heading.
I am using a twig to loop contents.

What I have tried is :

```
<div class="inbox_chat">
          {% set newArray = [] %}
          {% for msg in msg_details %}
          {% if msg.to_name not in newArray %}


        <div class="chat_list active_chat">
          <div class="chat_people">
            <div class="chat_img"> <img src="https://ptetutorials.com/images/user-profile.png" alt="sunil"> </div>
            <div class="chat_ib">
             <h5 id="txt-msg" onclick="viewMessage('txt-msg')">{{msg.to_name}} <span class="chat_date">{{msg.time}}</span></h5>
              
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        {% set newArray = newArray|merge([msg.to_name]) %}
         {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
          </div>
```

Javascript Code

```
<script>

function viewMessage(elementId){
document.getElementById(elementId).style.backgroundColor = 'green';
 }
 </script>
```

Here the only first name of displaying names changes when clicks. If I click another name in the list, then also the first name color changes. If I click a name on the list, I want to change that clicked name background color only. Not the first one background color.

What my output shows:

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r8rTw.png)

How to change the background color of the name when clicks.

Answer (score 0):

When you add the same `id` to multiple HTML elements and later on try to select an individual element by that `id`, javascript will select the first id that it could find in DOM, so that's why each `id` should be unique.

to solve this you can remove `id` and add the same `class` to elements, then pass `this` to the function that you are calling. when the function is called it will select all elements in the dom (with `querySelectorAll`) that has that `class` and remove styles from them, then will select the elements that you passed with `this`, and will change the color.

```
  <body>
    <h5 class="name" onclick="viewMessage(this)">this is a name</h5>
    <h5 class="name" onclick="viewMessage(this)">this is a name</h5>
    <h5 class="name" onclick="viewMessage(this)">this is a name</h5>
    <h5 class="name" onclick="viewMessage(this)">this is a name</h5>

    <script>
      function viewMessage(element) {
        document.querySelectorAll('.name').forEach((e) => (e.style = ''))
        element.style.backgroundColor = 'green'
      }
    </script>
  </body>
```

or you can use `addEventListener` to achieve the same thing with out `onclick` attribute on your elemnts. here is the code:

```
  <body>
    <h5 class="name">this is a name</h5>
    <h5 class="name">this is a name</h5>
    <h5 class="name">this is a name</h5>
    <h5 class="name">this is a name</h5>

    <script>
      const allNames = document.querySelectorAll('.name')

      allNames.forEach((names) => {
        names.addEventListener('click', (element) => {
          removeColor()

          element.target.style.backgroundColor = 'green'
        })
      })

      function removeColor() {
        allNames.forEach((name) => (name.style = ''))
      }
    </script>
  </body>
```

Comment: Not working , same as before.

Comment: @Binsha the code that I posted is working just fine, you can use it on your page, maybe you need to change some stuff on your side but the code is OK. as I mentioned you need to add `class` and remove `id` from your code.